# How to continuouslly fadein and out Button in Android?

Tags: android, animation, infinite

I want to fade in and out a Button in my android app when user activates a feature.
I saw examples on stackoverflow that shows fading in or out. But is there an easy way to combine in/out animations all together that repeats unlimited amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use on your `Animation` object the following :

```
myAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
myAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about your question, but this worked for me as a continue fadeOut and fadeIn animation:

```
int value = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<100000;i++){
        if (value == 0){
            doFadeOutAnimation();
            value = 1;
        }
        else if (value == 1){
            doFadeInAnimation();
            value = 0;
        }
    }
```